# Не отображается польностью текст в react google chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, angular2, google-chart

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
 <Chart
        width={'auto'}
        // height={'100%'}
        // width={'auto'}

        chartType="BarChart"
        loader={this.renderLoadingSign()}
        data={data}
        options={{
          chartArea: {
            //   width: '50%',
            height: '80%'
          },
          backgroundColor: 'white',
          bar: { groupWidth: 16 },
          fontFamily: variables.fontRegular,
          annotations: {
            alwaysOutside: true,
            datum: {
              stem: {
                color: 'transparent'
              }
            },
            domain: {
              stem: {
                color: 'red'
              }
            },
            textStyle: {
              fontName: variables.title14
            }
          },
          hAxis: {
            ticks: [0, 1],
            fontSize: 1,
            baselineColor: 'transparent',
            textStyle: {
              color: 'transparent',
              fontSize: 1
            },
            gridlines: {
              color: 'transparent'
            }
          },
          vAxis: {
            gridlines: {
              color: 'transparent'
            }
          },
          highlightOnMouseOver: false,
          enableInteractivity: false,
          legend: { position: 'none' }
        }}
        chartEvents={[
          {
            eventName: 'select',
            callback: ({ chartWrapper }) => {
              chartWrapper.getChart().setSelection([]);
            }
          },
          {
            eventName: 'ready',
            callback: ({ chartWrapper }) => {
              topItemsChart = chartWrapper.getChart();
              this.updateTextStyles();
              if (callback) callback();
            }
          }
        ]}
      />
```